# Select name from database by first character only

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to be able to find all the names in a database by its first character. For example:

```
$sql="SELECT name LEFT(".$_GET['abc'].",1) from `users` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 20";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

And output:

Letter: C

Names: Craig, Chris, Chad, etc.

I feel as if it's simple and for some reason I can't find it on Google. I also don't want to use `LIKE`, as I need it to be only the first character.

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Comment: ....especially as this query is ripe for SQL Injection regardless, and your database (and potentially your entire server) will get owned if you go this route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this :

```
SELECT name FROM `users` WHERE name LIKE 'c%'
```

`%` is the "joker" in SQL... with most DBMS

Comment: Yes. The "output" part isn't the role of sql from my point of view. Now maybe you guessed something else, but that's what I understand from the question...

Comment: Thank you, I was incorrect about Like, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @u_mulder: apparently OP didn't know that it can be done using LIKE :)

Comment: could you please specify which part of question we're missing :( " I also don't want to use LIKE, as I need it to be only the first character." shows that he didn't know that it can be done using LIKE :(

Comment: @u_mulder : And you apparently didn't read the OP's comment ! Anyway...so be it !

Comment: Is the case on the name important?

Comment: When using Mysql (and sqlserver too, couldn't tell for other DBMS), the collation used will tell whether the `like` is case sensitive or not. More explanation there : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

You query need to be changed a bit:

```
$first_letter = substr($_GET['abc'], 0, 1);
$sql="SELECT name from `users` WHERE LEFT(name ,1) = '" . $first_letter . "' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 20";
// OR SUBSTR variant
$sql="SELECT name from `users` WHERE SUBSTR(name, 1, 1) = '" . $first_letter . "' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 20";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Did you try to understand the full question ? ;-)

Comment: Nope. Just like anybody else. Satisfied?